# Not sure why my program wont display

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class BookData
{
    string Title;
    int Qty;
public:
    void setTitle(string in_title) { Title = in_title;}
    string setQty(int in_qty) { Qty = in_qty; }
    string getTitle() { return Title; }
    int getQty() { return Qty; }
};

int main()
{
    BookData book;
    book.setTitle("Starting Out with C++");
    book.setQty(10);
    cout << "Title is " << book.getTitle() << ".\n\n";
    cout << "Quantity is " << book.getQty() << ".\n\n"; 
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile all I get is an empty console. Any suggestions?

Comment: Compiles and prints everything perfectly fine for me. Btw, `setQty` shouldn't need a return type. Edit: ILDJARN! Stop that!

Comment: @Xeo : ***!!!*** (character limit padding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type of BookData::setQty() from string to void.

Without this change, it should still work fine. On my Linux machine, it crashes when setQty() is called with a return type of string and no string being returned.

Comment: It shouldn't even compile without returning a value. The only function that is allowed to do that is `main` afaik.

Comment: its working on my comp when setqty is void, but not when its string. why is it string in the first place???

Answer (score 0):

Does the console close immediately? If so, put this before `return 0;`:

```
System("PAUSE");
```

Or:

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

Or (for MSVC++2010):

```
int temp;
std::cin >> temp;
```